# Running Code after constructor in java?

Tags: java, constructor

I want to pass in the "seed" value into the constructor and then make a Random variable based on that seed value. I am not sure how to do this. Here is what I have going on:

```
public class Die
{

    private int seed;
    Random _randNum = new Random(seed);

    public Die(int seed) { this.seed = seed; }
}
```

From the main class I am creating that "Die" variable like this:

```
private Die _die1 = new Die(5);
```

Basically, I want the "seed" value to be 5 when the

```
Random _randNum = new Random(seed);
```

is ran. Any ideas as to how to make this happen?

Comment: You obviously know you can put statements in the constructor so I don't understand your confusion.

Comment: Declare `_randNum` then initialize it in the constructor...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change you code so that `_randNum` is instantiated in the constructor

e.g

```
public class Die
{
    private int seed;
    Random _randNum;

    public Die(int seed) { 
       this.seed = seed;  // actually no need to keep this value
       _randNum = new Random(seed);
    }
}
```